# Ошибка FAIL - Deployed application at context path / but context failed to start

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, tomcat

Как с этим бороться, подскажите пожалуйста?

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

BUILD SUCCESS

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Total time: 2.562 s

Finished at: 2016-01-20T04:35:21+04:00

Final Memory: 12M/226M

------------------------------------------------------------------------

NetBeans: Deploying on Apache Tomcat или TomEE

profile mode: false

debug mode: false

force redeploy: true

Undeploying ...

undeploy?path=/ProjectSpring

OK - Undeployed application at context path /ProjectSpring

In-place deployment  
at /Users/NetBeansProjects/ProjectSpring_MVC/target/ProjectSpring_MVC-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Deployment is in progress...

deploy?config=file%3A%2Fvar%2Ffolders%2Fbd%2Fz9714w313sl3j8csmz1pflfc0000gn%2FT%2Fcontext1603480033255008205.xml&path=/ProjectSpring

FAIL - Deployed application at context path /ProjectSpring but context failed to start
```

Log-файл Tomcat:

```
20-Jan-2016 16:28:40.347 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2]
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: init: Associated with   
Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'

20-Jan-2016 16:28:40.348 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: init: Global  
resources are available

20-Jan-2016 16:28:40.358 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: list: Listing 
contexts for virtual host 'localhost'

20-Jan-2016 16:28:40.377 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: list: Listing 
contexts for virtual host 'localhost'

20-Jan-2016 16:28:40.634 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: undeploy: Undeploying 
web application at '/ProjectSpring'

20-Jan-2016 16:28:41.171 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: install: Installing 
context configuration at 'file:/var/folders/bd/z9714w313sl3j8csmz1pflfc0000gn/T/context1094129628461986514.xml'

20-Jan-2016 16:28:48.599 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4]   
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: list: Listing contexts 
for virtual host 'localhost'

20-Jan-2016 16:28:48.612 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-5] 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: list: Listing contexts   
for virtual host 'localhost'

20-Jan-2016 16:28:48.753 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: undeploy: Undeploying  
web application at '/ProjectSpring'

20-Jan-2016 16:28:49.269 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: install: Installing 
context configuration at'file:/var/folders/bd/z9714w313sl3j8csmz1pflfc0000gn/T/context8234217066225316697.xml'
```

Comment: что говорят логи tomcat'а на который ты деплоишь?

Comment: Log-файл Tomcat приложен к вопросу.

Comment: Ты либо не все логи привёл, либо у тебя приложение задеплоилось успешно, т.к. ошибок я не вижу. Вообще maven имеет специальный [плагин для удалённого деплоя на tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/). Советую воспользоваться им, а не встроенной утилитой Netbeans'а

Comment: Ok, спасибо. Файл applicationContext.xml со спирговым контекстом находился в  папке "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF". Переместил applicationContext.xml в папку "src/main/resources" и все чудесным образом заработало. Видимо NetBeans не устраивает расположение файлов по "феншую")))